# Google Apps Script - Time Based Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm a complete novice, trying to set up a timed trigger. I have a spreadsheet with a list of emails, created a script that would send an email to each of them. If I run the script manually, it works just fine. I want a trigger that will automatically send the emails every 3 months.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234ID-here"); SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function (val) {
      var rowData = data[i];
      var emailAddress = rowData[1];
      var recipient = rowData[0];
      var phone = rowData[2];
      var skill = rowData[3];
      var address = rowData[4];
      var moreinfo = rowData[5];
      var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + "You signed up for the following skillshare:" + skill + "." +
        "If you would like to be removed from this list, or if the following contact info has changed, please reply to this email. Otherwise we will assume no change." +
        '\n\n' + address + '\n\n' + phone + '\n\n' + moreinfo + '\n\n' + 'Thanks!';
      var subject = 'Skill sharing list';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

If I run that, it works fine. Here's the other script I created for the trigger:

```
function createTimeTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1) //(to test it)
    .create();
}
```

Running this did nothing for me, looks like it had a 90% error rate with 119 executions as soon as I ran it. Help please?

*Edit - looks like it logged the error "Script function not found: sendEmails"

[image: Only have the two scripts]

[image: sendEmails snippet]

[image: trigger snippet]

[image: error]

[image: the one trigger I'm trying to add]

Answer (score 2):

Like I said, novice (as in, I just started learning this last night). I figured it out! I had created the scripts as two separate projects, but just realized that I can add a script to my sendEmails project....and now that both scripts are contained in one project it works beautifully! Haha thanks for the help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Your code to create a time based trigger looks correct. If it worked, you should be able to see your trigger(s) at: https://script.google.com/home/triggers

I'm guessing that the problem may be linked to your use of SetActiveSheet/getActiveSheet, which seems unneeded and might be leading to unintended issues or a crash when run from the context of a trigger.

Sheets do not need to be active for you to access them from your code, "active" in this context is relevant to the user interface.

Instead of that code, try accessing both the sheet and spreadsheet explicitly:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234ID-here").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
...
```

Comment: I do see it in my triggers. Changed the code, deleted the trigger, and ran it again....still no dice. Same high errors =/

Answer (score 0):

**Why it runs differently with a timebased trigger**

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234ID-here");  
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

When you run above function while a user interface is open it runs okay from whatever spreadsheet is open but when this is run from a timebased trigger it always runs on the server with no user interface open and it selects the active sheet as `ss.getSheets()[0]` which is the left most sheet in the spreadsheet.

So @Cameron Roberts solution will work just fine I just wanted let you know why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks, I did make those changes, but I'm still getting an error "Script function not found: sendEmails".

Comment: Perhaps you more than one function named sendEmails()

Comment: Please share the exact message.

Comment: Have you saved the script?

Comment: If you created the script manually you would have had to select the name and if there were two if would have warned you so presumably you created the trigger in code so you must have named it wrong.  Does it have extra spaces in it?

Comment: Everything was saved, and I ran my sendEmails function first to get past the authorizations. I edited my post with screenshots, these are literally the only two scripts I have haha.